# Generate set of all swap from 2 lists

Tags: python, generator, python-itertools, swap, enumeration

I use pyhton and would like to create something like a set of lists. I explain.
As input, I have a list like this :

```py
s = [[0,4,5,6,8],[1,2,3]]
```

I want to apply random swap on this s between all s[0] and s[1] elements. The problem is that I want to kind of enumerate (not explicitly) all the possible results of this swap. I have try some itertools stuff but didn't success.
In other words, the expected output is an iterable containing all possible swap from s.
Any advice is welcome !

```py
s = [[0,4,5,6,8],[1,2,3]]

def swap(s):
    i0 = randint(0,len(s[0])-1)
    i1 = randint(0,len(s[1])-1)
    s[0][i0],s[1][i1] = s[1][i1],s[0][i0]
```

Edit : I think I did not explain well the problem.
If we have as input :

```py
s = [[0,4,5,6,8],[1,2,3]]
```

The ouput would be something like :

```py
S = [[[1,4,5,6,8],[0,2,3]],
     [[0,1,5,6,8],[4,2,3]],
     [[0,4,1,6,8],[5,2,3]],
     [[0,4,5,1,8],[6,2,3]],
     [[0,4,5,6,1],[8,2,3]],
     [[2,4,5,6,8],[1,0,3]],
     ...
```

For each element e in S, e must be different from s by only one permutation of 2 elements

Comment: Can you show an example of output sequence please?

Comment: I just edit my post, I was not clear enough in my description

Comment: is the order important inside each list? [1, 4, 5, 6, 8], [0, 2, 3] is equal to [4, 1, 5, 6, 8], [0, 2, 3]?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if I get your question right, but you can use **[itertools.combinations](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations)** for generating **all possible swaps**.

```py
from itertools import combinations

listIn = [[0,4,5,6,8],[1,2,3]]

shortList, longList = sorted(listIn, key=len)

result = []

for longPart in combinations(longList,len(longList)-1):
    for shortPart in combinations(shortList,len(shortList)-2):
        longPart = list(longPart)
        shortPart = list(shortPart)
        p1 = longPart + shortPart

        p2 = list(set(longList) - set(longPart)) + list(set(shortList) - set(shortPart))
        result.append([p1, p2])
```

For your example the result list contains all 15 possible single-swaps.

Here an extract:

```py
[[0, 4, 5, 6, 1], [8, 2, 3]]
[[0, 4, 5, 6, 2], [8, 1, 3]]
[[0, 4, 5, 6, 3], [8, 1, 2]]
[[0, 4, 5, 8, 1], [6, 2, 3]]
[[0, 4, 5, 8, 2], [6, 1, 3]]
[[0, 4, 5, 8, 3], [6, 1, 2]]
[[0, 4, 6, 8, 1], [5, 2, 3]]
[[0, 4, 6, 8, 2], [5, 1, 3]]
[[0, 4, 6, 8, 3], [5, 1, 2]]
[[0, 5, 6, 8, 1], [4, 2, 3]]
[[0, 5, 6, 8, 2], [4, 1, 3]]
[[0, 5, 6, 8, 3], [4, 1, 2]]
[[4, 5, 6, 8, 1], [0, 2, 3]]
[[4, 5, 6, 8, 2], [0, 1, 3]]
[[4, 5, 6, 8, 3], [0, 1, 2]]
```

Comment: Note, you could just use `short_list, long_list = sorted(in, key=len)`, rather than the if/else where you assign shortest and longest list variables.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, @Chris .This is more pythonic than my complicated if/else. Adapted the code :)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer but in fact each element of the result list has to differ from s by only one swap

Comment: Ok, I see. The code can be shortened than. I've removed the unnecessary parts, maybe now it gets closer to the solution you are looking for, @bptste

Comment: just a remark: you don't solve the problem using just combinations so you will not get _all_ swaps (your statement is a bit... too strong)

Comment: Yes, the statement is too strong, made a mistake 
Thanks for the answer @ucczs I will work on this

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I misunderstood the question, but here is another way to do so if you want all combinations swapping an element of list 1 with an element of list 2.

We create a copy of the nested list and permute elements in those two lists.

```
s = [[0, 4, 5, 6, 8], [1, 2, 3]]

output = []
for i in range(len(s[0])):
    for j in range(len(s[1])):
        temp_s = [s[0].copy(), s[1].copy()]
        temp_s[0][i], temp_s[1][j] = temp_s[1][j], temp_s[0][i]
        output.append(temp_s)
```

---

**Output:**

```
[[[1, 4, 5, 6, 8], [0, 2, 3]],
 [[2, 4, 5, 6, 8], [1, 0, 3]],
 [[3, 4, 5, 6, 8], [1, 2, 0]],
 [[0, 1, 5, 6, 8], [4, 2, 3]],
 [[0, 2, 5, 6, 8], [1, 4, 3]],
 [[0, 3, 5, 6, 8], [1, 2, 4]],
 [[0, 4, 1, 6, 8], [5, 2, 3]],
 [[0, 4, 2, 6, 8], [1, 5, 3]],
 [[0, 4, 3, 6, 8], [1, 2, 5]],
 [[0, 4, 5, 1, 8], [6, 2, 3]],
 [[0, 4, 5, 2, 8], [1, 6, 3]],
 [[0, 4, 5, 3, 8], [1, 2, 6]],
 [[0, 4, 5, 6, 1], [8, 2, 3]],
 [[0, 4, 5, 6, 2], [1, 8, 3]],
 [[0, 4, 5, 6, 3], [1, 2, 8]]]
```